# .serialize contentEditable div?

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, contenteditable

I'm using (form).serialize to POST a form with ajax...

Something like:

```
    $.post("/ajax/post_message_action.php", $(form).serialize(), function (data) { ... }
```

The problem is that I want to use a contentEditable DIV instead of a

```
<textarea name="description">
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.post("/ajax/post_message_action.php",
    $(form).serialize()+"&description="+$('div[name=description]').text() ,
function (data) { ... });
```

Comment: In serialized data space will be converted to `+` signs but you're leaving description text with that. Maybe it should be `$.trim($('div[name=description]').text()).replace(' ','+')`

Comment: In Jishnu's code, the data from the DIV element is not escaped/sanitised which may result losing data. It may even prove vulnerable because if you aren't sanitising your JavaScript inputs properly you more than likely aren't sanitising it on the server end either. Use `encodeURIComponent` to sanitise the contentEditable data. `$(form).serialize()+"&description="+encodeURIComponent($('div[name=description]').text())`

Answer (score 1):

a. keep a hidden `textarea` element in the form.
b. on form submit, set the innerHTML of the div as the text in the textarea.